# Convert bytes representation of hex in int32 variable

Tags: c

```
char buffer[8];
memcpy(&buffer[0], "02000000", 8); //copy without '\0'
```

How can we interpret bytes in buffer as 0x00000002 and put it in the variable of type int?

Comment: better use `9` instead of `8` in order to cope for the string terminating NUL byte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You make it a string (with the terminating `'\0'`) and use [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) to convert it.

---

Byte-swapping an integer is simple:

```
#define SWAP16(x)  (((x) & 0xff00) >> 8) | (((x) & 0x00ff) << 8)
#define SWAP32(x)  (SWAP16(((x) & 0xffff0000) >> 16)) | (SWAP16((x) & 0x0000ffff) << 16)

uint32_t value = SWAP32(strtol("02000000", NULL, 16));
```

Comment: @Qwerty If you want the string `"00000002"` to become the hexadecimal value `0x00000002`, then pass the string `"00000002"` to `strtol`.

Comment: thanks for reply, but I want the string "02000000" to become 0x00000002. not "00000002" @JoachimPileborg

Comment: @Qwerty Then byte-swap it after the `strtol` call?